# Shared calendars through Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm viewing shared calendars in my app. It uses delegated workflow with permission Calendar.Read.Shared and Users.ReadBasic.All

I don't really understand how to sharing works when it comes to the API

1. Some users shared calendars are not shown when accessing /users/{userId}/calendars (they are visible in outlook)
2. Some users calendars are returned when using /users/{userId}/calendars but when trying to access the calendar events I get 403. Why are the calendar available to access but not the events? (they are visible in outlook).
3. I'm able to get both calendars and event in some cases

I'm guessing there are some settings on the calendars themselves that make this difference but I'm not able to see the difference in the calendar object I get from the /users/{userId}/calendars response or from the calendars when I view them in outlook.

I have verified the behaviour in Graph Explorer so it is not code related.

Is there another way to access all shared calendars?

Comment: Henrik, You may want to look at the documentation(s) and try the same when you Microsoft Graph API. Let me know how it goes. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-share-or-delegate-calendar?tabs=http
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-shared-events-calendars

Comment: Does the above helped you?